$\iint_{B} (5x^2+5y^2)dxdy$ where $B$ is $x^2+y^2+4x\leq0$
In polar coordinates
$$x=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta$$
then
$$x^2+y^2+4x=0\Rightarrow r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta+4r\cos\theta=0$$
i.e.,
$$r^2+4r\cos\theta=0\Rightarrow r(r+4\cos\theta)=0$$
Therefore,
$$0\leq r\leq -4\cos\theta,\quad \frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
So,
$$\iint_{B} (5x^2+5y^2)dxdy=5\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{0}^{-4\cos\theta}r^3drd\theta=320\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\cos^4\theta d\theta=120\pi$$
Is it correct?

HINT
You can also proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + y^{2} + 4x \leq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} + 4x + 4) + y^{2} \leq 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + 2)^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4
\end{align*}
Then you can make the change of variables:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x(r,\theta) = r\cos(\theta) - 2\\\\
y(r,\theta) = r\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $r\in[0,2]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.
Can you take it from here?
EDIT
Consider the triangle $\triangle OAX$, where $O = (0,0)$, $A = (-2,0)$ and $X = (x,y)\in \partial B((-2,0),2)$.
According to the cosine's law, one has that:
\begin{align*}
r^{2}(\theta) = |\overrightarrow{OX}|^{2} = |\overrightarrow{AO}|^{2} + |\overrightarrow{AX}|^{2} - 2|\overrightarrow{AO}||\overrightarrow{AX}|\cos(\pi - 2\theta) = 16\cos^{2}(\theta)
\end{align*}
where $\theta\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. Consequently, $r(\theta) = 4|\cos(\theta)| = -4\cos(\theta)$.
So the answer to your question is: yes, it is correct.
Hopefully this helps!

Yes, I thought about that too. I always have some doubts about polar coordinates when the circle is not centered in the origin. But the way I did is correct?

Since you have trouble using Polar coordinates when the circle is not centered at origin, you can also proceed as follows:-
The region $B$ is given by $(x+2)^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4$. So, make a change of variables $u=x+2$ and $v=y$.
Then in the $(u,v)$ coordinate plane, the region $B$ becomes $u^{2}+v^{2}\leq 4$, i.e. the area inside the disk of radius $2$.  Call this region as $D$ for notation.
Note that the Jacobian of the transformation is just $1$.
So the integral becomes $$5\cdot\iint_{D}(u-2)^{2}+v^{2}\,dudv$$
Now change to polar coordates by setting $u=r\cos(\theta)$ and $v=r\sin(\theta)$ and the region $D$ is given by $0\leq r\leq 2$.  Then the integral becomes
$$5\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\left((r\cos(\theta)-2)^{2}+r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)\right)\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=120\pi$$
which one can evaluate using elementary trigonometric integrals.
The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to worry about the limits of integration.
Note the difference between this approach and yours(as well as Atila's). You are transforming the coordinates of the integrand to make it easier and leaving the region of integration, which is a non- origin centered disk intact. This will lead you to carefully think about how the limits of integration will change.
However, I am changing the coordinates to make the region of integration more standard or canonical which leads to me having a non-standard integrand but I don't have to worry about the limits of integration. Instead, I am left with standard integral limits but with a slightly more complicated integrand, namely  $\left((r\cos(\theta)-2)^{2}+r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)\right)\cdot r$, instead of your rather simple $r^{3}$.
